# Apart from emulator, is android studio working fine in M1 macs

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, apple-silicon

I currently have a windows laptop with an intel i5. I am looking to upgrade to an M1 mac. Emulation isn't a problem for me(Virtualization is slower on ARM). Can any early adopter let me know if it is fast enough for basic android development and some Xcode?

Comment: Update: I have decided to go with an. intel macbook pro 16 inch, because ARM isn't ready for development yet.

Comment: Interesting, I bought a mac m1 last year, but last weekend just build a Ryzen hackintosh because of this. 

Comment: I wanted to add that, Ryzen CPUs are much slower at running Android emulator, because it doesn't support Intel HAXM/ acceleration which the emulators use.

Comment: Obligatory reminder to report problems with Android Studio on M1 to Google and not Stack Overflow: https://issuetracker.google.com (it's not directly a problem for this question, but leaving this comment here in an attempt to reduce M1 bug reports on SO that should go to Google, who can actually fix it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Available on Android Studio Arctic Fox (Beta)

The Beta version (Arctic Fox Beta 4) now has Apple Silicon support, so you can download it from [Android Studio download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview). Look for, for example: `Mac (Apple Silicon): android-studio-2020.3.1.19-mac_arm.zip (955253378 bytes)`. Don't use jetbrains toolbox because it is bit buggy, it downloaded an outdated version of Android Studio. I've noticed its also a day late on releases.

---

## Serious performance issues (before May 2021)

I've tried to use Android Studio for the past couple of months, and to me, it is unusable, let alone at parity with running it on Intel. I've always been on the **Canary** version too. I keep telling myself the M1 **is** faster, but I in reality I only notice speed reduction and freezes when compared to `MacBook Pro 16" 2020 2.3GHz 8‑core Intel Core i9` or my `Intel i7-9700K Hackintosh`. I also use a physical device to dedicate more mac resources to the IDE.

- Very slow indexing/ navigation around the code base
- Very slow typing and clicking sometimes (general lag)
- Random freezes which require app restart
- The compile times are the least of my worries (see bottom section).

---

Unfortunately, it is still very slow. Here I measure how long `./gradlew assembleDebug` takes after a warm up of the same (`./gradle assembleDebug`):

- `MacBook Pro 2.3GHz 8‑core Intel Core i9` **VS.** `Mac M1 Mini`
- `3 minutes and 1 second` **VS.** `4 minutes and 46 secinds`
- CPU Temperatures: `88 to 92C`(+hot air blowing out ) **VS.** `41 to 45C`

M1 chips are cool (in a temperature sense), but currently slow. I'll update when a Apple Silicon optimized Android Studio comes out.

Comment: I'll second all of the above. Some slowness is livable, but the random freezing gets really annoying. If you haven't yet saved a file, you lose all your changes when you have to restart. There is definitely hope though as IntelliJ IDEA CE (ARM version) works significantly better. It's not blazing fast, but it's definitely faster than Android Studio running on Rosetta. It also does not have the random freezes. I'd love to know the timeline on merging this version into Android Studio.

Comment: would you say a macbook pro 16" with core i7 or i9 would be reliable for android studio? including for running the emulator in the laptop. thinking of getting one but I would need the emulator and ideally for the app to not crash :(

Comment: Absolutely an intel one for Android Studio to function properly **today**. However, Google IO is this month, there might be an announcement about it (just my hope/ guess, I'm not certain) and you **might** get away with getting an M1 mac or wait: they are simply better cheaper and faster, while support across other apps are pretty much already there. I'll try it on my new 16gb m1 macbook and let you know if that might be sufficient.

Comment: Oh looks like good news [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html), Android Studio Canary 15 2020.3.1 is compatible with M1 macs, so I'll test it out now

Comment: For me Android Studio Canary 15 2020.3.1 is even slower than the latest stable Android Studio

Comment: Hi! 
Can you please run this **android studio benchmark test** on your Macbook M1 device and share your results? 

https://github.com/yozhik/AndroidStudioBenchmark    

**Results of Android Studio Performance testing:**
Excel table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AeeT_54b2VnovN4ikIsglh2Sc7U0bWxAarDKmGAJFtg/edit?usp=sharing

I have created fork from big Firefox app project to test this project against different hardware to understand what to buy. There are already 60+ results in the excel file. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using a Macbook Pro with M1 for Android development in Android Studio for the past few days. It does feel a little slow at times, but the fact that it was never an incredibly smooth application to begin with (on my old 13" MacBook Pro anyway) means it's not much different. Also, since it's under Rosetta 2 at the moment I'm pretty happy with the performance.

I'd say if you're not working on anything critical then it's fine. However, I'd still be wary of recommending it to people who need a reliable solution for work and if you need the Android emulator you're out of luck completely as you need to rely on a dedicated device.

Comment: hi! which MacBook pro do you have? thinking about getting the MacBook pro-16-inch with either core i7 or i9 but I definitely need to run the emulator on the laptop. Do you think this would work?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely okay for *basic* Android development. I've had a few instances where it has randomly frozen on me and I've had to do a force quit. And it doesn't particularly feel like it is quicker than the 2015 MacBook Pro I was running it on before(!) It is, however, very quiet (no fan!) and hopefully now that IntelliJ has been ported we can see a dedicated M1 version of Android Studio soon.

Comment: Hi! 
Can you please run this **android studio benchmark test** on your Macbook M1 device and share your results? 

https://github.com/yozhik/AndroidStudioBenchmark    

**Results of Android Studio Performance testing:**
Excel table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AeeT_54b2VnovN4ikIsglh2Sc7U0bWxAarDKmGAJFtg/edit?usp=sharing

I have created fork from big Firefox app project to test this project against different hardware to understand what to buy. There are already 60+ results in the excel file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the macBook air with m1 chip and it is fast every where but for android studio just forget about it , it crash every 1h especially when I create new class
or a new activity , like at least every 1h you will have a crash so you have to force quit the app and open it again .

Comment: HI it s me again and I want to correct my feedback about the Mac book m1 so now we are 2023 and android studio has released some stable versions where you can use the Macbook m1 without any issues. so now you can work as a mobile developer on a Mac book m1 without any problems

Answer (score 1):

Is anyone else using NDK with the M1?

I have two Android apps that I use Android Studio for. I tried both on my new M1 Mac mini.

One, relatively simple and Java only, builds fine.

The second has Java and C code (uses the NDK). Building it fails with a crash of Android Studio.

As a result of this, I'm having to develop on my legacy Intel MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

To use it, you need to download from: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and look for Mac (Apple Silicon), and you need to use Gradle 6.9-rc1+ .

Source: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html

Answer (score 0):

For compilation time reduce by 4, I found the best solution [here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/speed-up-android-compilation-in-apple-m1-device-6dbca65b4bb9).

We have in our project more than 1200 unit tests, the time to execute all this tests was 7-8 minutes, now with this JDK it only takes 1 minute and a half.

Best solution from Elye.