# How to improve performance of Android Studio in Apple M1 macs?

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

Using Android Studio in my new M1 MacBook pro seems to have some performance issues while coding. The application build is fast, but IDE seems a little laggy while coding, giving suggestions, and button response. What is the possible cause for this? Are there any ways to improve the performance of Android Studio? Activity Monitor indicates a lot of CPU usage from Android Studio.

Details about my Environment

- Android Studio Arctic Fox Preview Built
- Azul Zulu JDK 11

(Update)

The problem is solved now with official support

Comment: Did you consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop? Or using [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

Comment: No actually. I need the MacOS for IOS applications.

Comment: But GNU emacs runs on MacOS (download it from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#nonfree)...), and you could compile and even improve its source code, since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)

Comment: Maybe feedback to Google and see if they are aware of the issues or can do something about it?

Comment: Some performances issues are [already reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708%20performance%20mac) about MacOS. You could consider submitting your own bug report.

Comment: It is still bad performing for me as well. Either M1 sucks or Android Studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio/Emulator on macOS with ARM CPU M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176867/1079990

With Arctic Fox `aarch64` all is very fast !

Only NDK doesn't work on `aarch64`, there you need the `x86` variant

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same environment setup and also get the laggy experience.
I am on Big Sur 11.4 with a 16 GB M1 Macbook Pro.
I have really terrible performance, even doing basic things like resizing windows etc. brings out the spinner and even typing shows huge input lag.

--EDIT--
I have found that the IntelliJ Idea IDE doesn't have the laggyness whilst still having all the functionality of Android Studio. Maybe it can help you as a workaround until the issues with AS get resolved

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, mostly you would be using `x86` variant of Android Studio.
Try using the `arm64` Android Studio released by Google, meant for Apple M1.
Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69511170/6129580)