# Android studio compile time takes too much in MacBook Pro M1 chip

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

I am an Android developer. Recently, I bought a MacBook Pro(2020) M1 Chip having 16 GB Memory and 512 ssd. But the problem I am facing is, build and execution time of my code takes too much time. In fact, build time is very slow than my hp notebook having 8 GB Ram in Ubuntu. I really don't know, that to do now. How can I reduce my build and execution time. I am very disappointed with this Apple Product. If anyone having this issue, please share your experience, and suggestion if you could solve that issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [Apart from emulator, is android studio working fine in M1 macs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906525/apart-from-emulator-is-android-studio-working-fine-in-m1-macs)

Comment: Try this method, is the best.
https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/speed-up-android-compilation-in-apple-m1-device-6dbca65b4bb9